# Packer and Qemu - Qemu hangs during SIGKILL - reboot requested

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, packer

I'm attempting to build an Ubuntu 19.04 server image with packer. I have it booting and running the install seemingly fine, and after an hour and change, Qemu shows that the install is finished and a `SIGINT` and sometimes `SIGKILL` were sent, and a reboot requested, but eventually packer times out because Qemu never reboots the OS to let packer SSH in and finish its thing. I've tried a few things to get Qemu to output something about why it is failing to reboot:

`-serial stdio`

`-serial mon:stdio`

`-serial telnet:127.0.0.1:4444,server,nowait`

All to no avail. I get no feedback from Qemu about anything. I've also tried finding good examples to configure tracing and `-append console=ttyS0` with a kernel. I'm a Qemu and Packer nub, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. I've done a lot of searching around trying to find ways to debug qemu to figure out why it's hanging on reboot.

Ubuntu 19.04 Desktop build:

Packer: 1.4.1

Qemu: 3.1.0 (apt install)

macOS 10.14.5 build environment:

Packer: 1.4.0

Qemu: 4.0.0 (brew install)

In both environments, qemu seems to hang on the reboot part. I say seems, because while I do have `-display gtk` on the Ubuntu desktop and see where it hangs, there's a bug(?) and `-display sdl` is broken on Mac, and gtk doesn't work. I also tried curses on Mac, but that doesn't work either. So as best as I can tell, both break in the same spot. I can provide my preseed.cfg if needed.

Here's my `ubuntu.json`:

```
{
    "builders": [
        {
            "type": "qemu",
            "boot_command": [
                "<enter><wait2><esc><wait2><enter>",
                "<wait>",
                "/install/vmlinuz",
                " initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet",
                " vga=788",
                " auto=true",
                " priority=critical",
                " reboot=pci",
                " url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg",
                " --- <enter>"
            ],
            "qemuargs": [
                ["-display", "gtk"],
                ["-serial", "stdio"]
            ],
            "boot_wait": "5s",
            "disk_size": 20000,
            "headless": false,
            "http_directory": "http",
            "iso_url": "http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.04/release/ubuntu-19.04-server-amd64.iso",
            "iso_checksum_type": "sha256",
            "iso_checksum_url": "http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.04/release/SHA256SUMS",
            "communicator": "ssh",
            "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
            "ssh_password": "ubuntu",
            "ssh_port": 22,
            "ssh_wait_timeout": "120m",
            "shutdown_command": "echo 'ubuntu' | sudo shutdown -P now",
            "vm_name": "ubuntu-19.04-amd64.qcow2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was [bitten by a race condition](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-discuss/2018-10/msg00015.html). Building on Qemu 4 fixed it, and once I fixed my config file on macOS, I was able to get a build.